# sidenav with dots scrolled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sass

I asked similar question but didn't get an answer so I will try again. I have a single web page. In this page , I am trying to make a side navigation made out of Dots. Web page is broken to sections . I need to make it so every time I scroll to another section , the dot changes color. For example : First section - first dot is green, others are empty. Than if I go to 2nd section, the 2nd dot goes green and others are empty.
 Here is the fiddle :
https://jsfiddle.net/c1d3tfnL/2/

My guess is that there is a problem somewhere in this part

```
for (var i=0; i < aArray.length; i++) {
    var theID = aArray[i];
    console.log(theID);

    if (panel.hasClass('current')) {
      $("a[href='#" + theID + "']").addClass('greens');

  } else {
      $("a[href='#" + theID + "']").removeClass('greens');

  }
```

but I am not sure . Instead of having only one dot colored , They are all green.

You will see the dots in the top of the page but as I have an internal database I can't post everything here . It is supposed to look like this :
[image]

I have done everything including that it is fixed . This is how it looks now.

[image]

Every circle is always green . This is making me crazy .

Comment: I believe it has something to do with the dot click function. Also keep in mind that `panel` variable stores all elements with class `..panels` so you might reconsider this if `panel.hasClass('current')`

Comment: @Mojo Allmighty I don't think I have any click event , if that's what you mean. But for this Variable , you think I shouldn't store it like that ? I don't think I understand clearly :(

Comment: You can use `if($('#'+theID).hasClass('current'))`

Comment: @Mojo Allmighy i tried replacing my function with that but it doesn't color anything . The problem is that none of the a-elements in sidenav has class .current. This class is being added to Sections.

Comment: The id must be unique, you are using it in multiple places.

Comment: @Mojo Allmighty ah I see . my a-elements in sidenav have the same id's as my sections . So I should change the id's of the a-elements and put in the function you wrote

Comment: Yeah, or use an attribute for that, something like `section-id="YourSectionID"` and select it in your first for. You'll need to modify `var ahref = $(aChild).attr('id');` into `var ahref = $(aChild).attr('section-id');`

Comment: @Mojo Allmighty Ok so i tried this : `var aChildren = panel;
  var aArray = [];
  for (var i=0; i < aChildren.length; i++) {
    var aChild = aChildren[i];
    var ahref = $(aChild).attr('id');
    aArray.push(ahref);
  }

  for (var i=0; i < aArray.length; i++) {
    var theID = aArray[i];
    console.log(theID);
    if($(theID).hasClass('current')) {

      $("a[href='#" + theID + "']").addClass('greens');

  } else {
      $("a[href='#" + theID + "']").removeClass('greens');

  }`       This got me all sections but i still don't get the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183693/discussion-between-mojo-allmighty-and-bojan-kolano).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is selecting the sections. What you're doing right now is to take **all**  elements with class `panel` and try to see if it contains the class `current`. Having `if (panel.hasClass('current'))` will always return true because there will always be an element with class `panel` who has that class therefor all the dots will be green. You need a new selector to match your `a` with your sections.

```
<a section-id="hero" href="#hero" class="dot"><span class="hide">dot</span></a>
<a section-id="whole" href="#whole" class="dot"><span class="hide">dot</span></a>
<a section-id="split" href="#split" class="dot"><span class="hide">dot</span></a>
<a section-id="two-split" href="#two-split" class="dot"><span class="hide">dot</span></a>
<a section-id="three-split" href="#three-split" class="dot"><span class="hide">dot</span></a>
<a section-id="footer" href="#footer" class="dot"><span class="hide">dot</span></a>
```

As for your javascript code, you'll need to select the items with `section-id` attribute and check if the associated ID from sections has class `current`

```
var aChildren = $('.side ul').children();
var aArray = [];
for (var i=0; i < aChildren.length; i++) {
   var aChild = aChildren[i];
   var ahref = $(aChild).attr('section-id');
   aArray.push(ahref);
}

for (var i=0; i < aArray.length; i++) {
   var theID = aArray[i];

   if($('#'+theID).hasClass('current')) {
      $("a[href='#" + theID + "']").addClass('greens');
   } else {
      $("a[href='#" + theID + "']").removeClass('greens');
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What this does is  "Loop through all a-elements, and color them if the panel has the class "current"".
You problem: 
If the panel has class "current" color all a-elements green
What you want:
IF the panel has class current lookup the corresponding a-element (belonging to the panel) and addClass green.

So this does not check if the single a-element should get the class "greens" based on which panel is currently active ("current").

Without insight into the rest of the code you should/could do 1 of 2 things;

1. Loop through the panels and add the class "Greens" to the corresponding a-element.
2. Loop through the a-elements (as you're doing now), and check the corresponding panel element (the panel element that belongs to the a-element).

Depending on your code this might be as easy as:

```
$panel.find("a").addClass('greens');
```

---- edit ---

Although there's an accepted answer already you could do this with a somewhat easier to understand JS and HTML (without the loops and all).
On the panel you can add data-attributes with names that correspond to the a-elements you want to make green/active. When you are making the panel active you can also select the single a-element that corresponds to your panel (so panel with data-corresponding-link="hero" refers to the a-element with data-id="hero"), and just add the class green to it. 
You can choose to first select all a-elements and remove the class green or select the single a-element which has the class green and remove that single one.

```
<panel class="hero current" data-corresponding-link="hero"></panel>
<panel class="other-panel" data-corresponding-link="other-panel"></panel>
<a data-id="hero" href="#hero" class="dot"><span class="show">dot</span></a>
<a data-id="other-panel" href="#three-split" class="dot"><span class="hide">dot</span></a>
```

js:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

  var cutoff = $(window).scrollTop();

  panel.each(function(){
    if($(this).offset().top + $(this).height() > cutoff){
      panel.removeClass('current');
      $(this).addClass('current');

      $(".green").removeClass("green") //Select all the green classes and remove the class green (you could scope this further down to a.green or something).
      $("data-id='"+panel.dataset.correspondingLink+"']").addClass("green") //based on the panels corresponding-link data-attribute select the element(s) that have this data-attribute data-id set to "hero" and addClass green
      return false;
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: This is more of a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @sajoku This makes sense but my sidenav with dots is not in the sections . None of the sections have a . This sidenav is a separate thing on the page .

Comment: @sajoku The 2nd thing , Looping through a-elements sounds very close to what I need . Could you write an example or something ?

Comment: I added a way to do this without having to loop through all the a-elements.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how is your html looks, here I am giving sample code as it work same as you want.

**EDIT:** Added on scroll too

```js
$("ul li a").click(function(){
   $current=$(this);
  $("ul li").each(function(){
    $(this).removeClass("current");
  })
   $current.parent().addClass("current");
});


 var one_pos=$('#one').offset().top;
 var two_pos=$('#two').offset().top;
 var three_pos=$('#three').offset().top;
 var four_pos=$('#four').offset().top;
 var five_pos=$('#five').offset().top;
 
 $(window).on('scroll', function() {
  
    var current_pos = window.pageYOffset;
    if(current_pos>one_pos && current_pos<two_pos){
        $("ul li a[href='#one']").click();
    }else if(current_pos>two_pos && current_pos<three_pos){
        $("ul li a[href='#two']").click();
    }else if(current_pos>three_pos && current_pos<four_pos){
        $("ul li a[href='#three']").click();
    }else if(current_pos>four_pos && current_pos<five_pos){
        $("ul li a[href='#four']").click();
    }else if(current_pos>four_pos){
        $("ul li a[href='#five']").click();
    }
 
 })
```

```css
div{
height:200px;
padding:2%;
border:1px solid;
}
ul{
position:fixed;
list-style:none;
}
ul li.current i{
   color:green;
}
ul li i{
   color:#ddd;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.css">
  

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<ul>
<li class="current"><a href="#one"><i class="fa fa-circle"></i></a></li>
<li><a href="#two"><i class="fa fa-circle"></i></a></li>
<li><a href="#three"><i class="fa fa-circle"></i></a></li>
<li><a href="#four"><i class="fa fa-circle"></i></a></li>
<li><a href="#five"><i class="fa fa-circle"></i></a></li> 
</ul>

<div id="one">one</div>
<div id="two">two</div>
<div id="three">three</div>
<div id="four">four</div>
<div id="five">five</div>


<div>rest</div>
```

Comment: This is what i initially thought too but then the OP said he doesn't have any `click` function so i think the dots will be colored on scroll not on click

Comment: Yeah this works great but i need this to work the same , but on scroll

Comment: @BojanKolano updated code with on scroll trigger. I hope this will helps you.

Comment: @DilipBelgumpi Thats even better ! This is a great solution but i need it to be not hard coded . This way if someone adds a new section, the nav wont work anymore :(

Answer (score 0):

OK so after some time and lots of help, this is the solution :

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

  var cutoff = $(window).scrollTop();

  panel.each(function(){
    if($(this).offset().top + $(this).height() > cutoff){
      panel.removeClass('current');
      $(this).addClass('current');
      return false;
    }
  })

  var aChildren = $('.side ul').children();
  var aArray = [];
  for (var i=0; i < aChildren.length; i++) {
    var aChild = aChildren[i];
    var ahref = $(aChild).attr('section-id');
    aArray.push(ahref);
  }

  for (var i=0; i < aArray.length; i++) {
    var theID = aArray[i];

    if($('#'+theID).hasClass('current')) {

      $("a[href='#" + theID + "']").addClass('greens');

  } else {
      $("a[href='#" + theID + "']").removeClass('greens');

  }
}
```

Thanks to @Mojo Allmighty